# Insert or replace when column matches specific value

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `gid` INT NOT NULL,
  `x` INT NOT NULL,
  `y` INT NOT NULL,
  `z` INT NOT NULL,
  `type` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ( `gid`, `x`, `y`, `z` )
);
```

The combination of `gid`, `x`, `y`, `z` is unique. There can be multiple rows with the same `gid` and `type` as long as the `x`/`y`/`z` values are different.

However, I want the combination of `gid` and a specific `type` value to be unique. For example, there can only be one row per `gid = x` with `type = 1`, but there can be multiple rows with `gid = x` and `type = 2`. I know that I can declare a unique constraint for `gid` and `type` and then use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE VALUE UPDATE ..`, however I only want that to work when `type` equals 1.

Any solution for this?

EDIT: A solution for MySQL has been found. However, this does not work with MariaDB. What is the MariaDB solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve it with function index(supported by MySQL 8.0.13 and newer):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX myIndex ON test(gid,(CASE WHEN `type` = '1' THEN `type` END));
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c89f43d87f4d1fa24564f67103206c1e)**

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `gid` INT NOT NULL,
  `x` INT NOT NULL,
  `y` INT NOT NULL,
  `z` INT NOT NULL,
  `type` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ( `gid`, `x`, `y`, `z` )
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX myIndex ON test(gid,(CASE WHEN `type` = '1' THEN `type` END));

INSERT INTO `test`(gid, x,y,z,`type`) VALUES (1,1,1,1,1);
INSERT INTO `test`(gid, x,y,z,`type`) VALUES (1,2,2,2,1);
-- Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'myIndex'

INSERT INTO `test`(gid, x,y,z,`type`) VALUES (3,1,1,1,2);
INSERT INTO `test`(gid, x,y,z,`type`) VALUES (3,1,2,2,2);
SELECT * FROM `test`;
```

---

> Can I add the unique index on table creation?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `gid` INT NOT NULL,
  `x` INT NOT NULL,
  `y` INT NOT NULL,
  `z` INT NOT NULL,
  `type` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ( `gid`, `x`, `y`, `z` ),
  UNIQUE INDEX myIndex(gid,(CASE WHEN `type` = '1' THEN `type` END))
);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=39b9460f33d5efce9897805228388021)**

Comment: Note that you need at least MySQL 8.0.13 for this to work.

Comment: Before 8.0.13 a similar approach should also work with a unique key containing a generated column.

Comment: I noticed this does not work with MariaDB. What is the MariaDB equivalent?